# DependencyProperty of type Int64, set in XAML

Tags: silverlight, xaml, silverlight-4.0

I have DependencyProperty ShowDelayProperty of type long. 
In the XAML I'm trying to set this property like

```
<TextBox ... tooltip:ToolTipService.ShowDelay = "0" ... />
```

And getting exception:

> Failed to create a 'System.Int64' from the text '0'. [Line: 630
>   Position: 172]

Also I tried use 0L with the same exception. 
How can I set this property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>You have two options:</strike>

1. Implement a [TypeConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverter%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) for the type you want to set in XAML

<strike>2. Use a long-hand setter</strike>

```
     xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"

     <TextBox>
         <tooltip:ToolTipService.ShowDelay>
             <system:Int64>0</system:Int64>
         </tooltip:ToolTipService.ShowDelay>
     </TextBox>
```

**Edit:** So long hand setters don't work. In fact it turns out that they dont work for a number of primitive types. [More reading](http://geekswithblogs.net/codingbloke/archive/2010/05/14/silverlight-iconvertible-typeconverter.aspx)

`Option 1 is still viable.`

There are two other options besides the long hand setter:

1. Add a resource from code behind and set

   `tooltip:ToolTipService.ShowDelay = "{StaticResource MyResource}"`
2. Set it from code

Comment: I've tried your second suggestion but getting "The type 'Int64' was not found"

Comment: I've added the namespace you need to use. Try that!

Comment: I've used exactly that namespace.

Comment: I've found a workaround and just set this property from code behind, but anyway thanks for option 1, didn't know about this. Oh this silverlight... :)